# Python - Modifying rows of a data frame where the column ID is equal to each other and creating a growth variable based on their difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a list of thousands of companies that all have about 90 columns of variables.

All the companies are identified with a specific ID for each company, and several rows of data from each year. The rows for each company are not after each other:

Example:

| row# | Year | dummy variable | Variable 1 | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2001 | NaN | 50000 | XX |
| 1 | 2001 | NaN | 40000 | YY |
| 2 | 2001 | NaN | 100 | ZZ |
| 3 | 2001 | NaN | 7000000 | LL |
| 4 | 2002 | NaN | 55000 | XX |
| 5 | 2002 | NaN | 60000 | YY |
| 6 | 2002 | NaN | 150 | ZZ |
| 7 | 2003 | NaN | 60000 | XX |
| 8 | 2003 | NaN | 80000 | YY |
| 9 | 2003 | NaN | 200 | ZZ |
| 10 | 2003 | NaN | 182042 | DD |

I want to add a column called "growth" and have it show the growth from 1 year to the next IF there is a previous year with the same ID, and then show the change in variable 1 between 2003 and 2002, (which should be added to 2003 row for that ID) then between 2002 and 2001 (and be added to 2002 growth column).

So it needs to be a function that looks at companies with the same ID, sees if there is a row with the same ID for the previous year, and then adds the growth between those years to the column.

Any help or link or other resources would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried quite a few approaches but unfortunately my coding skills in python are not at this level yet and I am a bit stumped at combining the different requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a basic dataframe that has your kind of data layout. Is this correct?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'company': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
     'year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2017, 2018],
     'sales': [221, 245, 276, 124, 214]})

df['change'] = df['sales'] - df.sort_values(['company', 'year']).groupby('company')['sales'].shift(1)
```

What this does is this: use the current value of the sales for each company and subtract the sales from the year before. The groupby just looks up the last value for each company. Please note that if a year would be missing, it would compare it with the sales from two year ago.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. And if possible, try to include a Minimal Reproducible Example next time :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Good luck with your project!